# "invalid argument: 'id' can not be string" when trying to switchToIFrame() in PHP

Tags: php, selenium, iframe, behat

```
    public function switchActionScopeToIframe($name)
    {
        $this->getdriver()->switchToIFrame($name);
    }

$this->switchActionScopeToIframe("my-iframe-name");
```

I've also tried to do this from getSession(). Same result.
I've also tried with other selectors. Same result.
I've also tried to index like `switchToIFrame(1);` since my iframe is the second one. No error on this one, but then it doesn't find any elements inside the iframe, like fields.
I've also tried to rename the iframe myself with javascript. Same result.

Comment: How is `my-iframe-name` defined?

Comment: Sorry. That was supposed to be a string. ```<iframe name="my-iframename" ...>. Not sure if it affects but the iframe is followed by #document that contains the <html>

Comment: Based on your HTML it should be `$this->switchActionScopeToIframe("my-iframename")`;

Comment: the "my-iframe-name" is a placeholder. the problem is not the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after adding this to the behat.yml

```
        capabilities:
          extra_capabilities:
            goog:chromeOptions:
              w3c: false
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal Mink I added the capability like so.

```
extensions:
    Drupal\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2:
        wd_host: 'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'
        browser: 'chrome'
        capabilities:
          ...
          extra_capabilities:
            chromeOptions:
              w3c: false
              ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the specifications of [Switch To Frame](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#switch-to-frame):

> The [Switch To Frame](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-frame) command is used to select the [current top-level browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-current-top-level-browsing-context) or a [child browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-child-browsing-context) of the [current browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-current-browsing-context) to use as the [current browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-current-browsing-context) for subsequent commands.

The remote steps are:

- Let id be the result of getting the property "id" from the parameters argument.
- If id is not null, a Number object, or an Object that represents a web element, return error with error code invalid argument.
- If the current browsing context is no longer open, return error with error code no such window.
- Handle any user prompts and return its value if it is an error.
- Run the substeps of the first matching condition and incase the id represents a web element:

  - Let element be the result of trying to get a known element by web element reference id.
  - If element is stale, return error with error code stale element reference.
  - If element is not a frame or iframe element, return error with error code no such frame.
  - Set the current browsing context to element’s nested browsing context.